# Dlink Dir-605L QOS any alternative?

Tags: wireless-router

605L I tried to use the traffic control but when the other laptop stream using youtube or download my latency for online games rise up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither traffic control nor QoS can help here. The earliest you can do something to a packet is when you receive it. And by the time you receive these packets, they've already consumed your bandwidth to your ISP. Consumer Internet access simply cannot handle high-bandwidth and latency-sensitive applications at the same time.

You may be able to help by installing traffic limiting software on the other laptop. Limit it to just a tiny bit less than the maximum throughput it normally gets. This should minimize the buffering your ISP does, and that's what's killing your latency.

Comment: the router doesn't have qos what to do?

Comment: @superdb It doesn't matter whether the router has QoS or not. The router doesn't control what traffic is put on the link, your ISP does. Either install traffic limiting software on the laptop, negotiate times when you can play with whoever uses it, or upgrade your Internet plan.